# How to await parameter from client correctly?

Tags: php, web-applications

I send string from cliet to server by GET method. Its a street and buils number in format like that:

```
Lenina, 51
```

On server i parse it:

```
    $str = $_GET["street"];
    $adr_array = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $str);
    $street = $adr_array[0];
    $build = $adr_array[1];
    if($build!=null){
...do something....
}
```

But what if i get only:

```
Lenina
```

Of course i get error becouse `$adr_array[1]` not exist.
 In this case how to handle that i not got build number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if [*is set*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) element in array or not:

```
//Your code omitted
$build = isset($adr_array[1]) ? $adr_array[1] : null;
//Your code omitted
```

P.S. Are you sure you want to receive street and building number like that? Maybe you want to have separate input fields? I advise doing so because it will make your code cleaner. But this is only suggestion because I don't know what your UI look likes.

Comment: Thanks for isset. i was thought about it but two fields take more space. Single field looks idial http://smeijer.github.io/GeoSearch/

Comment: @KliverMax Yes, it looks nice. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php):

```
if(array_key_exists(1, $adr_array)){
     //Street number given
}
```

or like so:

```
$build = array_key_exists(1, $adr_array) ? trim($adr_array[1]) : null;
```